# Oracle - SQL Query Optimization - Query runs for a long time

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, query-optimization

I have a scenario where customer data is created in one schema and pushing to another schema for business operations. In some cases, the data is not pushed so I am using the below query to identify missing data. But it is kept on running, not returning the data as both tables are having more than 5 million records. How to optimize and get the result?

```
SELECT CUSTID FROM SCHEMA1.CUSTOMER WHERE CUSTID NOT IN(SELECT ID FROM SCHEMA2.CUST_TBL);
```

After adding one more filter, the query response is same.

```
SELECT CUSTID FROM SCHEMA1.CUSTOMER WHERE CUSTID NOT IN(SELECT ID FROM SCHEMA2.CUST_TBL WHERE CUST_TYPE=0);
```

CUSTID and ID are indexed, unique, and not null columns. CUST_TYPE is not null but not indexed.
Also tried with `/*+parallel(50)*/`

Oracle version: 19c

Comment: Depending on your Oracle version, `not in (subquery)` can be a problem when `custid` or `id` are nullable columns. If so, you could try adding `where id is not null` to the inner query (assuming neither column needs qualifying with the table name), or rewriting it as `not exists`. Also, `parallel(50)` is excessive. I'd start with plain `parallel` and let Oracle decide.

Comment: Actually, now that I check (e.g. [here](http://structureddata.org/2008/05/22/null-aware-anti-join/)), the null-aware anti-join was added way back in 11g so probably the nullable column isn't an issue in your case. If you could share the execution plan and your Oracle version that would be helpful.

Comment: both id and custid fields are mandatory and indexed fields. Using Oracle 19c version

Comment: passing one more filter cust_type to inner query and is also not null column.

SELECT CUSTID FROM SCHEMA1.CUSTOMER A WHERE CUSTID NOT IN(SELECT ID FROM SCHEMA2.CUST_TBL B and *B.cust_type=0* );

Comment: I think the updated version is missing a `where` keyword. But anyway the execution plan would be helpful, along with more detailed numbers. How many rows does the query return? How many rows does the revised subquery return?

Comment: yea it's `where`. revised subquery returns around 3.5M records and checking against 5M records. 
on using bobC() query it is taking around 380 secs to return the results. 
`select custid
from SCHEMA1.CUSTOMER c1
left join SCHEMA2.CUST_TBL c2
on c1.custid = c2.id
where c2.id is null and c2.CUST_TYPE=0`;

Comment: It needs to check 5M rows to see whether they aren't in a set of 3.5M rows. Indexes won't help with that and will most likely make it slower. If that's what happening it should be clear from the execution plan. Did you try Littlefoot's MINUS approach?

Comment: Yes, it helps. Thanks, William

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried not exist.

```
SELECT CUSTID FROM SCHEMA1.CUSTOMER A WHERE NOT EXIST
(SELECT 1 FROM SCHEMA2.CUST_TBL B WHERE A.ID = B.ID );
```

Answer (score 1):

Minus requires sorting, so is not very efficient. A better approach would be an outer join:

```
select custid
from SCHEMA1.CUSTOMER c1
left join SCHEMA2.CUST_TBL c2
on c1.custid = c2.id
where c2.id is null
```

If you have enough resources (CPU, IO, memory), you can use parallelism to improve the performance further.

Answer (score 0):

How about the `minus` set operator?

```
select custid from schema1.customer
minus
select id from schema2.cust_tbl;
```

Comment: Minus does require sorting.